# Git Error While Publishing Lerna Monorepo to NPM via GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, npm, lerna, github-actions

I use the following GitHub Actions (new `YAML` version) workflow to publish packages from my `lerna` monorepo to push to `master`:

```
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:

  deployPackages:
    name: Deploy Packages
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Checkout master
        run: git checkout master

      - name: Install
        uses: nuxt/actions-yarn@master
        with:
          args: install

      - name: Build
        uses: nuxt/actions-yarn@master
        with:
          args: build

      - name: Lint
        uses: nuxt/actions-yarn@master
        with:
          args: lint

      - name: Test
        uses: ianwalter/puppeteer@v1.0.0
        env:
          CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID: ${{ secrets.CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID }}
        with:
          entrypoint: yarn
          args: test:ci

      - name: Deploy Packages
        uses: nuxt/actions-yarn@master
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          DEPLOYING_USER_NAME: ${{ secrets.DEPLOYING_USER_NAME }}
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        with:
          args: deploy:ci

      - name: Build Docs
        uses: nuxt/actions-yarn@master
        with:
          args: docs

      - name: Deploy Docs
        uses: maxheld83/ghpages@v0.2.1
        env:
          BUILD_DIR: _site/
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The `deploy:ci` npm script executes the following bash script:

```sh
echo "Authenticating with Registry..."
npm config set registry //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN -q

echo "Adding Git Remote..."
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin "https://$DEPLOYING_USER_NAME:$GH_PAT@github.com/SCOPE/REPO_NAME.git"
git fetch
git tag -d master

echo "Configuring CI Git User..."
git config --global user.email octobot@github.com
git config --global user.name GitHub Actions

echo "Publishing Packages..."
npx lerna publish \
  --message "chore: release new versions" \
  --yes
```

that results in the following error:

```
lerna info execute Skipping releases
lerna info git Pushing tags...
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: git push --follow-tags --no-verify origin master
lerna ERR! error: src refspec refs/heads/master matches more than one.
lerna ERR! fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
lerna ERR! error: failed to push some refs to 'https://***:***@github.com/SCOPE/REPO_NAME.git'
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR!     at makeError (/github/workspace/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
lerna ERR!     at Promise.all.then.arr (/github/workspace/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
```

What is causing the above error?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing, "src refspec refs/heads/master matches more than one", means that what you're trying to push matches more than one revision.  If the refspec given were, say, `master`, then the likely situation is that you have both a branch and a tag called `master`, and Git wouldn't know which one you wanted to push.

In this case, it's possible that you have either a branch and tag both named `master` or you have a `refs/heads/master` (the `master` branch) and either a `refs/heads/refs/heads/master` (which is the `refs/heads/master` branch) or `refs/tags/refs/heads/master` (which is the `refs/heads/master` tag), and Git is getting confused.

It looks like you're trying to delete a `master` tag in your script, which is likely the source of your issues.  You'll probably want to fix whatever is causing that tag to be created so that you don't have this issue anymore.  Without seeing your repo, though, it's hard to tell exactly what the cause is here.

Comment: `git tag -l | grep master` has no output, so I don't have a `master` tag. the line `git tag -d master` was a naive attempt to avoid this error and can be ignored. Essentialy, In order to push tags to the repo (part of the lerna workflow), I need to reestablish the remote, according to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/101743224?noredirect=1